# Read 2-dimensional array into R

Tags: r

My data is stored in a text file that looks like this:

```
1, { {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {2, 6} }

2, { {0, 3}, {2, 2}, {0, 1} }
...
```

The first element is an integer, and the second is a 2-dimensional array. Is there a function that reads this into R?

Comment: what do you want it to look like once it's read in?

Comment: ideally as a list of arrays or a 2-dimensional array as it is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 data.frame( lapply( read.csv(text=
"1, { {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {2, 6} } # will read the line as mostly character columns 
 2, { {0, 3}, {2, 2}, {0, 1} } # with '{' and '}' just as non-syntactic characters
", header=FALSE              ), 
     function(x) as.numeric( gsub("[^[:digit:]]", "", x) ) 
           )        )
#----------------------
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7
1  1  0  1  1  0  2  6
2  2  0  3  2  2  0  1
```